# django RestFrameWork _OneToOneField serializer .create() FOREIGN KEY constraint failed

Tags: python, django, django-rest-framework, one-to-one

I have two models in my django project. AdIfo, and AdGame. The model Adgame has OneToOne relation with AdIfo.in django admin panel. I can build properly Object AdGame model. But when I try making in serializer the error is :IntegrityError

```
 FOREIGN KEY constraint failed
```

Models.py:

```
class AdIfo(models.Model):
    address = models.TextField(max_length=250)
    price = MoneyField(max_digits=12, decimal_places=0, 
           default_currency="IRR")
    phonenumber = models.CharField(validators=[phone_regex], 
           max_length=17, null=True, blank=True)
           ad_status = models.BooleanField()



class AdGame(models.Model):
    CONSOLE_GAME = (
        ('XBX', 'Xbox'),
        ('PS4', 'Play Station 4'),
        ('PC', 'Personal Computer'),
         )
    GAME_REGION = (
        ('1', 'USA'),
        ('2', 'Europe'),
        ('3', 'MiddleEast'),
        ('j', 'Japan'),
        ('4', 'Australia'),
        ('N', 'Unknown')
        )
    title = models.CharField(max_length=25)
    game = models.ForeignKey(Game, on_delete=models.CASCADE)
    console = models.CharField(max_length=3, choices=CONSOLE_GAME)
    game_region = models.CharField(max_length=1, choices=GAME_REGION)
    ad_info = models.OneToOneField(AdIfo, related_name='ad_info', 
          primary_key=True, on_delete=models.CASCADE)
          description = models.TextField(max_length=500, blank=True)
    owner = models.ForeignKey(User, related_name='ad_owner', 
          on_delete=models.CASCADE)
    image = StdImageField(upload_to=UploadToClassNameDirUUID(), 
          blank=True, variations={
          'large': (800, 600),
          'medium': (600, 400),
          'small': (300, 200),
          'thumbnail': (100, 100, True),
           })
          publish_date = models.DateTimeField(auto_now=True)

    def __str__(self):
       return self.title
```

serializers.py

```
class AdInfoSerializer(serializers.ModelSerializer):
    """ad information serialization"""
    phonenumber = serializers.IntegerField()

    class Meta:ad_info=adgame,
        model = AdIfo
        fields = "__all__"


class AdGameSerilizer(serializers.ModelSerializer):
    '''  Ad model serialization '''
    ad_info = AdInfoSerializer(required=True)
    console = serializers.ChoiceField(choices=AdGame.CONSOLE_GAME)
    game_region = serializers.ChoiceField(choices=AdGame.GAME_REGION)
    owner = serializers.PrimaryKeyRelatedField(read_only=True, 
            default=serializers.CurrentUserDefault())
    image = serializers.ImageField()

    class Meta:
        model = AdGame
        fields = [
                'ad_info',
                'title',
                'game',
                'console',
                'game_region',
                'image',
                'owner',
                'description',
                'publish_date',
                ]

    def create(self, validated_data):
        info_data = validated_data.pop('ad_info')
        adgame = AdGame.objects.create(**validated_data)
        AdIfo.objects.create(ad_info=adgame, **info_data)
        adgame.save()
        return adgame

    def update(self, instance, validated_data):
        info_data = validated_data.pop('ad_info')
        instance.ad_info.address = info_data.get('address', 
                                             instance.ad_info.address)
        instance.ad_info.price = info_data.get('price', 
                                             instance.ad_info.price)
        instance.ad_info.phonenumber = info_data.get('phonenumber', 
                                        inad_info=adgame,stance.ad_info.phonenumber)ad_info=adgame,
        instance.ad_info.ad_status = info_data.get('ad_status', 
                                          instance.ad_info.ad_status)
        instance.title = validated_data.get('title', instance.title)
        instance.image = validated_data.get('image', instance.image)
        instance.console = validated_data.get('console', 
                                                  instance.console)
        instance.game = validated_data.getad_info=adgame,('game', instance.game)
        instance.game_region = validated_data.get('game_region', 
                                              instance.game_region)
        instance.description = validated_data.get('description', 
                                              instance.description)
        instance.owner = validated_data.get('owner', instance.owner)
        info = instance.ad_info
        instance.save()ad_info=adgame,
        info.save()
        return instance
```

I know my problem is in django rest framework you must handle the `create()`. The model AdIfo must be created first and then AdGame.I tried to pass the AdIfo's id for Adgame as a kwargs but my knowledge is not enough.I realized the AdIfo doesn't pass the id from AdInfoSerializer into AdGameSerilizer.but for testing I made a view for AdInfoSerializer .and everything was fine the id field will be included in my result.

Comment: Paste error completely on pastebin and add link to your answer

Comment: https://pastebin.com/GNUEqbGh

Comment: @shalbafzadeh check the link please